# Mount subfolder of already mounted disk

Tags: mount

I have this disk mounted

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/user/other type ext4 (rw,relatime) [other]
```

Then I mount these other 2 folder

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/user/other/mega type ext4 (rw,relatime) [other]
/dev/sda3 on /media/user/other/gdrive type ext4 (rw,relatime) [other]
```

**I am not sure if I can mount more folder for the same path (/dev/sda3)**  (I trying to import into Nextcloud as external storage but gives error)
How can I check if works properly?

With `mount -l | grep 'other'` print the 3 lines above

`sudo mount -a` give no output

Comment: `/dev/sda3` isn't a "path".  It's a block device.  What exactly are you trying to do? "mount subfolder of already mounted disk" doesn't make any sense - what, exactly, do you mean by that?   If you want to access subdirectories in that mounted filesystem, just do it - all files and dirs in that fs will be under that mount-point, they don't need to be mounted individually.

Comment: While your ultimate goal is not clear to me, you can use *bind mounts* to mount directories, or you can use *symbolic links* if you need several paths to the same directory.

Comment: yes, after some searches I solved the issue with bind